# Parse.com connecting MongoLab URI to Parse Dashboard

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mlab

I have trouble connecting my mongodb database to Parse Dashboard using the required URI :

```
mongodb://user:password@dsXXXXX.mongolab.com:XXXXX/my_db?ssl=true
```

Here is what I get :

[image: Parse Dashboard Screenshot]

I'm completely new to mongdb and mongolab and cannot figure out what's going on.

Comment: Is this for a Dedicated plan with MongoLab? Those are the only plans that support SSL. If you haven't already, reach out to MongoLab support: support@mongolab.com.

Comment: I have reached them and I indeed need a dedicated plan in order to use ssl. It works without the `?ssl=true`

Answer (score 0):

I using Heroku and MongoLab for Parse,
And the URI I am using, I've got from Heroku app setting page as follows:
[image: heroku app settings page]